# php find time between time range array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Consider the following is my time range array,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00:00-01:00
    [1] => 01:00-02:00
    [2] => 02:00-03:00
    [3] => 03:00-04:00
    [4] => 04:00-05:00
    [5] => 05:00-06:00
    [6] => 06:00-07:00
    [7] => 07:00-08:00
    [8] => 08:00-09:00
    [9] => 09:00-10:00
    [10] => 10:00-11:00
    [11] => 11:00-12:00
    [12] => 12:00-13:00
    [13] => 13:00-14:00
    [14] => 14:00-15:00
    [15] => 15:00-16:00
    [16] => 16:00-17:00
    [17] => 17:00-18:00
    [18] => 18:00-19:00
    [19] => 19:00-20:00
    [20] => 20:00-21:00
    [21] => 21:00-22:00
    [22] => 22:00-23:00
)
```

and I have result array fetching from database,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [registration_time] => 2:10
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [registration_time] => 5:10
            [count] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [registration_time] => 15:30
            [count] => 6
        )
)
```

I am trying to find out `registration_time` in my time range array but that is not working. My strategy is to use `array_search()` functionality but its not working. I want below output:

```
Array
(
     00:00-01:00 => 0
     01:00-02:00 => 0
     02:00-03:00 => 2
     03:00-04:00 => 0
     04:00-05:00=> 2
     05:00-06:00=> 0
     06:00-07:00=> 0
     07:00-08:00=> 0
     08:00-09:00=> 0
     09:00-10:00=> 0
     10:00-11:00=> 0
     11:00-12:00=> 0
     12:00-13:00=> 0
     13:00-14:00=> 0
     14:00-15:00=> 0
     15:00-16:00=> 6
     16:00-17:00=> 0
     17:00-18:00=> 0
     18:00-19:00=> 0
     19:00-20:00=> 0
     20:00-21:00=> 0
     21:00-22:00=> 0
     22:00-23:00 => 0
)
```

Comment: yes miken32 it is very helpful thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the Hour only from the Result Array:

```
foreach ($Array_from_DB as $value) {
    $time= strtotime($value.registration_time);
    $result_array[date('H'),$time]+=$value.count;
}
```

loop the array from the database (for each element), convert it to time variable, get the hour only, and the result array will have the count of all database counts, after that you can do a loop from o to 23, check if isset($result_array[$loopvariable]) if is not set, put a 0 count for example.

$arra

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Make your array of time ranges indexed by number of seconds. Then convert each time into number of seconds and compare which index it matches:

```
$ranges = array(
    60 => array("range"=>"00:00-00:59", "count"=>0),
    120 => array("range"=>"01:00-01:59", "count"=>0),
    180 => array("range"=>"02:00-02:59", "count"=>0),
    // etc
    1440 => array("range"=>"23:00-23:59", "count"=>0),
);
foreach ($registrations as $reg) {
    $t = explode(":", $reg["registration_time"]);
    // turn HH:MM into minutes
    $minutes = ($t[0] * 60) + $t[1];
    // round to the nearest 60
    $minutes = ceil($minutes / 60) * 60;
    $ranges[$minutes]["count"] += $reg["count"];
}

foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    $output[$range["range"]] = $range["count"];
}
print_r($output);
```

This will allow you to easily change to periods other than one hour in the future if desired.

If you're always going to be using hours:

```
$ranges = array(
    0 => array("range"=>"00:00-00:59", "count"=>0),
    1 => array("range"=>"01:00-01:59", "count"=>0),
    2 => array("range"=>"02:00-02:59", "count"=>0),
    // etc
    23 => array("range"=>"23:00-23:59", "count"=>0),
);
foreach ($registrations as $reg) {
    list($h, $m) = explode(":", $reg["registration_time"]);
    $ranges[$h]["count"] += $reg["count"];
}
foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    $output[$range["range"]] = $range["count"];
}
print_r($output);
```